# System Log Error Message

Tags: magento2, php, error

I have this error in my exception log

> main.WARNING: Subscription for MBI service has been failed. An error occurred during token exchange: {"message":"Handshake request failed."}.

What is causing this? I am on Magento 2.3.1 and PHP 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to **Advanced Reporting**. You can find this error under **Magento_Analytics** module.

There is a cron which checking the connection

> vendor/magento/module-analytics/Model/Connector/SignUpCommand.php

```
public function execute()
{
    $result = false;
    $integrationToken = $this->integrationManager->generateToken();
    if ($integrationToken) {
        $this->integrationManager->activateIntegration();
        $response = $this->httpClient->request(
            ZendClient::POST,
            $this->config->getValue($this->signUpUrlPath),
            [
                "token" => $integrationToken->getData('token'),
                "url" => $this->config->getValue(Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL),
            ]
        );

        $result = $this->responseResolver->getResult($response);
        if (!$result) {
            $this->logger->warning(
                sprintf(
                    'Subscription for MBI service has been failed. An error occurred during token exchange: %s.'
                    . ' Content-Type: %s',
                    !empty($response->getBody()) ? $response->getBody() : 'Response body is empty',
                    $response->getHeader('Content-Type')
                )
            );
        }
    }

    return (bool)$result;
}
```

**How to fix this error?**

You can take any action from the following:

1. Create an account in advanced reporting for magento.
2. Disable **analytics_subscribe** cron
3. Ignore this error, this is not any error if you not use magento advanced reporting
4. Block this code by overwriting this class
5. Disable from config
   [image]
   [Learn more](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html)

Comment: How do I fix the error?